# v-text will override element children

Tags: vuejs3

Learning vuejs and so far the tutorial running code works fine until I was told to change this

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ text }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>
<script setup>
const text = 'Directive text';
</script>
```

which ran fine to this

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1 v-text="text">Loading...</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

the script remains the same. Now it throws this error

```
[plugin:vite:vue] v-text will override element children.

1  |  <template>
2  |    <div>
3  |      <h1 v-text="text">Loading...</h1>
   |           ^
4  |    </div>
5  |  </template>
```

I've tried changing the variable name from `text` to `test`.

Comment: Remove the `Loading...` part from your template.

Comment: [v-text](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-text) sets the textContent of the element, so it's a mistake to include `v-text` and actual text between your element tags, since v-text overrides the latter (as indicated by the error)